# Документирование кода

Tags: c#, документация

Передо мной стоит задача вынести все summary комментарии в отдельные файлы в виде документации со своим форматом. Не нашёл либу, которая позволяет это делать именно со своим форматом. Для лучшего понимания пример.

Метод:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get element by ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">ID.</param>
    /// <param name="timeOut">Waiting timeout.</param>
    /// <returns>Element.</returns>
    protected static ReturnType GetElementByID(string id, int timeOut)
    {
        //method body
    }
```

Его документация с форматом:

```
**GetElementById**(id, timeOut) - Get element by ID.
Arguments:
1. id - _string_ - ID.
2. timeOut - _int_ - Waiting timeout.

Result - _ReturnType_ - Element.
```

Не подскажете, может всё-таки есть такая либа? Или есть идеи как быстро сделать парсер для .cs файлов (парсить в кастомный тип и сохранять его в файле со своим форматом)?

Comment: Идея для парсера - искать блоки, начинающиеся с `///`, оборачивать их слева в `<docs>`, справа в `</docs>`, чтобы они становились валидным XML-текстом, а потом парсить в модель и из модели форматировать уже в такой формат, какой вам захочется.

Comment: @aa_talanin, нашёл ещё одну идею для парсинга. Можно в настройках проекта включить генерацию XML комментариев. Там уже всё в XML формате лежит. Удобнее парсить даже. Сорсы: https://habr.com/ru/post/102177/.

Comment: Да, это получше моего решения будет, я что-то забыл про возможность генерировать .xml - доки вдобавок к бинарям.